# Склоняется ли порода собак джек-рассел-терьер?

Tags: склонение

Склоняется ли порода собак джек-рассел-терьер?

Answer (score 3):

Склоняется без родового слова **порода**:

Щенки породы джек-рассел-терьер, приехал с джек-рассел-терьером, рассказывал о своём джек-рассел-терьере, но рассказывал о породе джек-рассел-терьер.

Можно сказать и так: терьер Джека Рассела, о терьере Джека Рассела, но это уже не официальное название породы, а указание на имя того, кто вывел эту породу.

Comment: Думаю, тут проявилось некое правило (тенденция), по которому подобные названия перенесены из английского в русский. "Jack Russell terrier" переводится именно как "терьер Джека Рассела", но превратился в джек-рассел-терьера. Недавно был вопрос о двигателе "Стерлинг-Дельфин» — то же явление, в первоисточнике он называется Sterling Dolphin engine